# Finding common values for factor variable and list with different number of levels

Tags: r, factors

I have 2 variables: SIZE, which contains the house sizes split in 4 levels by their size, and GROUP2, which contains the houses split in 5 levels by the quintiles of their age. (new_baltimore is the house dataset).
Code:

```
SIZE <- cut(new_baltimore$SQFT,breaks=quantile(new_baltimore$SQFT), labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), include.lowest = TRUE)

GROUP1 <- cut(new_baltimore$AGE, breaks=quantile(new_baltimore$AGE, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/5)), include.lowest=TRUE)
GROUP2 <- split(new_baltimore, GROUP1)
names(GROUP2) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

I want to find the combinations of the 2 variables (for example, house that belongs in GROUP2$A and has a size that belongs in SIZE$A). Then compute mean and sd for each combination and compare.

I tried

```
q <- split(GROUP2, SIZE)
```

but it gives the error

```
Warning message:
In split.default(GROUP2, SIZE) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

EDIT: when I run q, I get this. So it is not just a warning.

```
function (save = "default", status = 0, runLast = TRUE) 
.Internal(quit(save, status, runLast))
<bytecode: 0x000002e24eba7808>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

The data:

```
good_struct <-
  structure(
    list(
      new_baltimore.AGE = c(
        148L,
        9L,
        23L,
        5L,
        19L,
        20L,
        20L,
        22L,
        4L,
        23L,
        20L,
        30L,
        18L,
        75L,
        60L,
        65L,
        14L,
        45L,
        14L,
        22L,
        35L,
        5L,
        60L,
        14L,
        19L,
        11L,
        16L,
        19L,
        17L,
        24L,
        22L,
        27L,
        3L,
        21L,
        20L,
        4L,
        40L,
        23L,
        35L,
        25L,
        17L,
        26L,
        15L,
        29L,
        24L,
        30L,
        19L,
        50L,
        18L,
        74L,
        22L,
        24L,
        20L,
        7L,
        47L,
        50L,
        45L,
        48L,
        50L,
        48L,
        55L,
        27L,
        20L,
        33L,
        40L,
        25L,
        25L,
        40L,
        30L,
        40L,
        22L,
        25L,
        29L,
        49L,
        35L,
        55L,
        30L,
        15L,
        40L,
        35L,
        70L,
        25L,
        25L,
        30L,
        30L,
        50L,
        25L,
        70L,
        55L,
        40L,
        70L,
        20L,
        20L,
        25L,
        18L,
        20L,
        2L,
        8L,
        25L,
        18L,
        30L,
        35L,
        21L,
        20L,
        24L,
        13L,
        25L,
        18L,
        30L,
        20L,
        22L,
        28L,
        50L,
        20L,
        38L,
        17L,
        22L,
        27L,
        25L,
        25L,
        25L,
        30L,
        60L,
        22L,
        30L,
        28L,
        45L,
        100L,
        60L,
        50L,
        35L,
        50L,
        24L,
        50L,
        33L,
        40L,
        50L,
        25L,
        48L,
        10L,
        45L,
        20L,
        25L,
        25L,
        22L,
        21L,
        29L,
        18L,
        2L,
        19L,
        49L,
        10L,
        25L,
        16L,
        17L,
        27L,
        34L,
        2L,
        24L,
        23L,
        40L,
        25L,
        45L,
        26L,
        37L,
        15L,
        22L,
        75L,
        28L,
        31L,
        100L,
        15L,
        80L,
        75L,
        23L,
        15L,
        21L,
        2L,
        25L,
        23L,
        0L,
        4L,
        40L,
        55L,
        21L,
        45L,
        50L,
        5L,
        50L,
        22L,
        22L,
        6L,
        18L,
        18L,
        23L,
        3L,
        1L,
        47L,
        21L,
        29L,
        0L,
        29L,
        24L,
        22L
      ),
      new_baltimore.SQFT = c(
        1.0451592,
        2.6867559168,
        2.8446910848,
        2.4266274048,
        2.0475830016,
        3.6622378368,
        2.0327185152,
        2.378317824,
        4.0988821248,
        1.8469124352,
        1.1222687232,
        1.0210044096,
        1.189158912,
        2.7675815616,
        1.328513472,
        1.2746297088,
        1.0999719936,
        1.6778289024,
        0.9959205888,
        0.8324112384,
        1.3359457152,
        3.41418672,
        1.8580608,
        2.1200473728,
        2.3095695744,
        1.783738368,
        1.0758172032,
        2.41547904,
        1.337803776,
        1.0795333248,
        2.1442021632,
        2.2073762304,
        1.449287424,
        0.9290304,
        2.118189312,
        1.5570549504,
        2.053157184,
        1.3266554112,
        1.4269906944,
        1.48644864,
        2.1404860416,
        2.3170018176,
        1.0981139328,
        1.1965911552,
        1.040514048,
        1.6834030848,
        3.55354128,
        1.6425257472,
        1.7670158208,
        3.047219712,
        1.4084100864,
        2.041544304,
        1.170578304,
        2.1850795008,
        1.6276612608,
        4.4231137344,
        1.909157472,
        3.2999159808,
        0.780385536,
        1.2709135872,
        1.3452360192,
        1.189158912,
        1.189158912,
        1.67225472,
        1.430706816,
        0.9364626432,
        0.8324112384,
        0.8324112384,
        1.8580608,
        1.1965911552,
        1.11483648,
        1.6871192064,
        1.3266554112,
        2.41547904,
        1.1166945408,
        1.932383232,
        1.0943978112,
        0.8063983872,
        1.635093504,
        1.059094656,
        4.138830432,
        4.3032688128,
        0.9513271296,
        0.891869184,
        2.898574848,
        2.452640256,
        1.263481344,
        2.5529755392,
        1.6592482944,
        1.6759708416,
        1.3786811136,
        0.9717657984,
        1.3526682624,
        0.6466051584,
        0.88257888,
        1.1018300544,
        1.1965911552,
        1.1445654528,
        0.6243084288,
        0.9364626432,
        1.449287424,
        0.6243084288,
        1.0702430208,
        1.0925397504,
        0.9513271296,
        1.0702430208,
        0.8621402112,
        0.6243084288,
        1.449287424,
        1.43999712,
        0.9141659136,
        1.449287424,
        1.2783458304,
        0.9513271296,
        0.5351215104,
        0.9364626432,
        1.0702430208,
        1.128771936,
        0.9076627008,
        1.3935456,
        1.337803776,
        1.34709408,
        2.0940345216,
        0.9513271296,
        0.724643712,
        0.780385536,
        1.0145011968,
        3.985540416,
        0.83612736,
        0.97548192,
        0.9364626432,
        1.170578304,
        0.8324112384,
        0.7971080832,
        0.7023469824,
        1.003352832,
        1.2486168576,
        0.9513271296,
        1.3415198976,
        1.1371332096,
        1.226320128,
        0.891869184,
        1.4139842688,
        2.2445374464,
        0.9513271296,
        0.9513271296,
        0.9178820352,
        2.155350528,
        1.6425257472,
        2.257543872,
        3.3389352576,
        2.006705664,
        1.0237915008,
        1.95096384,
        2.2222407168,
        1.337803776,
        2.60128512,
        1.0628107776,
        2.0382926976,
        0.9513271296,
        1.5663452544,
        0.9215981568,
        1.2486168576,
        1.11483648,
        1.3712488704,
        0.8324112384,
        1.0702430208,
        0.8026822656,
        0.7543726848,
        1.0330818048,
        1.0479462912,
        0.9624754944,
        1.0702430208,
        1.588641984,
        1.6276612608,
        0.9968496192,
        1.040514048,
        1.189158912,
        1.11483648,
        3.8155278528,
        1.189158912,
        2.0773119744,
        0.9810561024,
        1.2486168576,
        1.0237915008,
        1.6703966592,
        1.7540093952,
        1.0925397504,
        0.8695724544,
        1.0702430208,
        2.536252992,
        2.1404860416,
        1.6425257472,
        1.2411846144,
        1.077675264,
        1.0702430208,
        0.9271723392,
        1.2040233984,
        1.0340108352,
        1.820899584,
        1.0702430208,
        1.1297009664,
        0,
        0.9884883456
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-204L)
  )
```

Comment: @JahiZamy no it is an error. I have edited my post to show the output.

Answer (score 0):

It would be ***a LOT*** easier to write the size quartiles and the age quintiles to the data frame instead of ripping apart the data frame and then trying to recombine or match different subsets: keep your data in one place, and don't keep unnecessary copies.

##### store quantiles in data frame

```
new_baltimore$SIZE_QUARTILE <- cut(new_baltimore$SQFT,
                                   breaks=quantile(new_baltimore$SQFT),
                                   labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                                   include.lowest = TRUE)

new_baltimore$AGE_QUINTILE <- cut(new_baltimore$AGE,
                                  breaks=quantile(new_baltimore$AGE, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/5)),
                                  labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                                  include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Resulting structure:

[image]

##### filter data frame

Now filtering is super easy:

```
new_baltimore[new_baltimore$SIZE_QUARTILE=='A' & new_baltimore$AGE_QUINTILE=='A',]
```

```
    AGE      SQFT SIZE_QUARTILE AGE_QUINTILE
19   14 0.9959206             A            A
78   15 0.8063984             A            A
95   18 0.8825789             A            A
100  18 0.9364626             A            A
108  18 0.6243084             A            A
116  17 0.9364626             A            A
166  15 0.8324112             A            A
172  15 0.9624755             A            A
176  15 0.9968496             A            A
197   1 0.9271723             A            A
```

Or, with the popular package `dyplr`; it's a little more user-friendly, though it doesn't preserve the row names:

```
library('dplyr')
new_baltimore %>%
  filter(SIZE_QUARTILE == 'A', AGE_QUINTILE == 'A')
```

```
   AGE      SQFT SIZE_QUARTILE AGE_QUINTILE
1   14 0.9959206             A            A
2   15 0.8063984             A            A
3   18 0.8825789             A            A
4   18 0.9364626             A            A
5   18 0.6243084             A            A
6   17 0.9364626             A            A
7   15 0.8324112             A            A
8   15 0.9624755             A            A
9   15 0.9968496             A            A
10   1 0.9271723             A            A
```

##### Further processing

Given your intentions to create multiple combinations of variables and compute statistics on them, I would advice looking into `dplyr`; it's worth learning to use it. See for instance [this introduction](https://datacarpentry.org/R-genomics/04-dplyr.html#split-apply-combine_data_analysis_and_the_summarize()_function), especially the paragraph *"Split-apply-combine data analysis and the summarize() function"*.